# Debugging Apple app site association file in swift

Tags: arrays, ios-universal-links, apple-app-site-association

[This screenshot includes of result debugging aasa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxyFm.png) I integrate the universal link into my app by (associated domain) and then debug the universal link on the real device but I get this error from swcutil_show.txt to trace whether the universal link works fine or not so in the screenshot [this image includes of configure aasa file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwGiM.png) so I need to know this issue relate to backend dev team or this issue related from my side in mobile dev

Comment: You should use inline images, not links to images.